# Change the schema.org generator to include the title element text as name property

Tags: feature-request, title, seo

Apparently, [Google](https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2308751%2Fwhat-is-a-memory-heap) is using the name of [the QAPage](https://schema.org/QAPage) schema, ignoring the title HTML element. [Other search engines are not doing that](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=heap%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&ia=web). We include the first tag in the title to make sure the most popular tag is always included on the search result.

This isn't technically SEO (we did that for SEO reasons), but in this case, it's hurting the researchers ability of accurately find the questions they are asking, since it's not our preferable title.

Comment: Do you have any source for Google using the QAPage schema to get the title? I did some testing and it looks like it uses the title element, but sometimes moves the tag prefix to the end or strips it out (but does keep the `- Stack Overflow` bit).

Comment: @Smitop well, maybe it's not exactly QAPage schema, but it's something akin to it. It's at least a smoking gun considering that [it's literally removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4dZA.png). Maybe something to do with the featured snippets thingy. Remember, Google behavior is just a black box, I started with the "apparently" for that reason.